# Update gcc11.0 to gcc13.1 and compile the program but segmentation fault

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, g++

I have update my compiler gcc-11.3.0 to gcc-13.1.
`gcc-v`

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.1.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../configure -enable-checking=release -enable-languages=c,c++ -disable-multilib
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 13.1.0 (GCC)
```

`g++ -v`

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.1.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../configure -enable-checking=release -enable-languages=c,c++ -disable-multilib
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 13.1.0 (GCC)
```

I compile the program, `g++ main.cpp -std=c++20 -o main` successfully.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  std::cout << "hello world\n";
  return 0;
}
```

however, when I run it `./main` . It says `16553 segmentation fault  "/home/gaoxiang/project/minilog/"main`
And then I use `ldd` to check the program

```
> ldd main
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff498c4000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f5251274000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f525118d000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f525116d000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5250f45000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f52514bd000)
```

I use gdb to debug the program, gdb shows that:

```
Starting program: /home/gaoxiang/project/minilog/main
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000155555406f5a in std::ostream::sentry::sentry(std::ostream&) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
```

I donot know how to deal with it

Comment: What linux distro? How did you update GCC? Usually the common wisdom is to not touch the system GCC, and install the new one alongside it (named `gcc-13`, or whatever).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I use wsl2 (the Ubuntu 22.04 lts). I use wget to download the gcc13.1 and compile, install it

Comment: What does `which gcc` say? What commands did you use to compile and install it?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It says `/usr/local/bin/gcc` I just use `make -j8` to compile and use `sudo make install` to install it

Comment: You know you can install it from PPA instead of building it yourself? https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test?field.series_filter=jammy That worked for me out of the box.

Comment: "sudo make install to install it" It's a very, very, VERY bad idea. Note how your executable references the system libraries instead of those that come with your newly build gcc. From the point of view of that new shiny gcc, those system libraries are outdated and unsupported. Recommendation: remove everything in `/usr/local`. install gcc from PPA.